# Delete cells depend on thier values works fine but skipped the half

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete 2 or more (variable depending on work) cells in the same row starting from row 2 if the 2 cells are = ""

I used this code and it's already working fine except 1 problem

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim s As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    For s = 2 To 22
        If ws.Range("G" & (s)) = "" And ws.Range("H" & (s)) = "" Then
            Union(ws.Range("G" & s), ws.Range("H" & s)).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next s
End Sub
```

the problem is if I have for example from G2:H4 (2rows or more achieve the if condition) it's only delete half of them,

if 5 rows delete 3 only...etc

so I think the loop doesn't operate on the current cell (just guessing)

Attach screens is before and after running the code for more clarification

before

[image: before]

after

[image: after]

Comment: In general you want to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code. When deleting lines like that you need to start at the bottom: `For s = 22 To 2 step -1`

Comment: how can I delete the cells without using select? also starting from the bottom cause excel hanging and should be restarted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim s As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

For s = 22 To 2 Step -1

    If ws.Range("G" & s).Value = "" And ws.Range("H" & s).Value = "" Then 
        ws.Rows(s).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        'or:
        'ws.Range("G" & s & ":H" & s).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End if

Next s

End Sub
```

After running the code:
[image]

Comment: I edited to match the sheet names :). Okay I actually made a few edits just in case :))

Comment: Yes, Right, sorry for asking about select quickly without think about it, about step backwards I don't know why if I do that the excel keep searching and searching with no end, so I should restart the excel itself before the code ends (it keeps searching on row 22

Comment: Ok, now after added '.Value' the crashing issue solved, but still deleting only the half results if the empty cells under each others, kindly recheck the attached screens

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Could you maybe edit your question and show us a screencap of the desired result?

Comment: photos attached already, for example in first photo the range that should be delted is (G5:H5) and (G6:H6) , but the delted is only one of them after execute the code

Comment: solved after change s from Integer to Long, and moving backwards, and avoid select , many thanks to your Awesome help

Comment: FYI, Excel allows for more rows than `Integer` can handle. as a rule, you should always use `Long` since `Integer` has no benefit over it